# Get order of variables in scope after dynamic OrderBy

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-orderby

I currently have:

```
ng-repeat="pesron in people | orderBy:variable"
```

As events occur, the variables changes and thus the order of the persons changes as well. 
**Question**: How do I access the people in the controller as an array, ordered appropriately?

I tried:

```
angular.forEach($rootScope.people, function(value,index) {  
    console.log(value);  
});
```

However, this only gives the variables in the order that they are added to the scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject `$filter` into your controller, and do the following

```
var orderedPeople = $filter('orderBy')($scope.people, 'variable')
```

If you want this to change whenever `variable` changes, then you'd need to put the assignment in a `$scope.$watch`.

However, the bigger picture is that you probably shouldn't structure your app this way. Namely, you're

1. Filtering your array on every digest cycle, even though `variable` only changes once in a while.
2. Filtering it in your view and then repeating that work in the controller.

The following would be more efficient:

In your controller:

```
people = []; // initialize me
$scope.$watch(function() { return people; }, sortList, true); 
// we're resorting whenever any property on $scope.people changes.
// This isn't the best solution if people is a huge and complex object
function sortList() {
  $scope.orderedPeople = $filter('orderBy')(people, 'variable');
}

// somewhere else
doSomethingWith($scope.orderedPeople);
```

In your view:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in orderedPeople"></div>
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Works great, thank you. The latter approach is certainly better for the long-term.